# How to temporary stop calculating computed when executing multiple array push/remove operations

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have `computed` which based on `observableArray` property `headers`. Also i have methods for adding and removing multiple `headers`:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.headers = ko.observableArray();
    self.newHeaders = ko.computed(function() {
        var countOfNew = 0;
        ko.arrayForEach(self.headers(), function(header) {
            if (!header.id) {
                countOfNew++;
            }
        });
        return countOfNew;
    });

    self.addHeaders = function(headers) {
        ko.arrayForEach(headers, function(header) { 
            self.headers.push(header);
        }
    };

    self.removeHeaders = function(headers) {
        ko.arrayForEach(headers, function(header) { 
            self.headers.remove(header);
        }
    };
}
```

When i call `addHeaders` or `removeHeaders`, `newHeaders` called for each item in `headers` array. There is any solution how temporary stop calculating computed field? (someting like as `ko.valueWillMutate`, `ko.valueHasMutated` which used for subscribers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Knockout.js Performance Gotcha #2 - Manipulating observableArrays](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html)

> A better pattern is to get a reference to our underlying array, push
>   to it, then call .valueHasMutated(). Now, our subscribers will only
>   receive one notification indicating that the array has changed.

I forked **Ryan Niemeyer** jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3EMH/1/) .. Open the console and check how many times the message `'calling computed object'` is logged!.

Comment: Or using `push.apply`... `this.children.push.apply(this.children, newChildren);`... oh that page does mention this.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that an observable array is still just an observable. You can get the array's value `var arr = oarr()`, do whatever you want with it, and put it back in `oarr(arr)`.

Comment: what about performance? I think that assigning a modified array into `observableArray` property doesn't increase performance. What do you think?

Comment: It does. In your example, the value is recalculated on every push. If you extract it, use the plain JavaScript push, and re-assign, the value will be recalculated only once.

Comment: I'm traing to improve performance, decrease calling computed function. I fear that assigning a modified value to `observableArray` will be more slower, than additional calls computed function.

Comment: The way your computed is implemented, it's called whenever the array is modified, and always iterates thorough all items. Why are you saying it will be slower?

Comment: I have about 200 headers, when i'll assign a modified array to `observableArray`, knockout will be render all headers on view. The time for this operation is greater, then time for calculation computed.

Comment: And what do you think happens when you call `.valueHasMutated()`?

Comment: Will be notified all subscribers, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Knockout 3.1.0 includes the [`rateLimit` extender](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/303eb3070ced451e6f3769a7b3d30c45d511cf6f/documentation/rateLimit-observable.md) that can improve performance in this scenario quickly and easily. Simply apply the extender to your observable array:

```
self.headers = ko.observableArray().extend({rateLimit: 0});
```

(Version 3.1.0 is currently [3/3/2014] available as a beta release.)

If you're only interested in delaying the computed observable (and not everything that's dependent on the array), you can apply the `rateLimit` extender to the computed observable instead. If you're using Knockout 3.0 or earlier, you can use the `throttle` extender on the computed to achieve a similar result:

```
self.newHeaders = ko.computed(function() {
    ...
}).extend({throttle: 1});
```

Comment: Unfortunately i use v3.0(

Comment: In 3.0, you can use the `throttle` extender on the computed observable  if that's all you want to delay (`throttle` doesn't work on the observable array though).

Comment: Yes, i know about `throttle`, but solution with underlying array, is more preferably for me.

Comment: Michael, I forked Ryan Niemeyer's jsfiddle from http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html here http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/o59q9vqr/1/ and it seems that the "add new bad" button only reevaluates once now that I've added ".extend({ rateLimit: 0 });" to the items observable array. Is it okay to now push to an observable array if rateLimit is used?

Comment: @sfors Yes, it's fine. With 3.4.0, you can also use `extend({deferred:true})` instead of `rateLimit`.